# Change closest input val?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, find, closest

I have an instance where my datepickers won't work by button click, so I figure find the closest input and .click() or .focus() (for it's datepicker, since the same field is to be affected). For the sake of this demo, from the button/icon click - find the closest input and focus/click on it. If correct, the border will glow blue. http://jsfiddle.net/81tvr0op/

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <div class="input-group date">
                <input type="text" />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn default" type="button">
                        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                        Icon
                    </button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </th>    
    </tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery**

...something like

```
$(".date > span > button").on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).closest("th").find("input:text").click();
            });
```

...right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to place the cursor into the input box when the user clicks the button.

To do that, you should use `.focus()` instead of `.click()`.

**Working example:**
http://jsfiddle.net/81tvr0op/1/

Answer (score 0):

From your jsfiddle, something like this should work.

```
$("button").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().siblings(0).focus();
});
```

Or, give your input an id and do something like:

```
$("button").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#dateInput").focus();
});
```